# Use Python to read RTD data from excel

Tags: excel, python-3.5, rtd

I have an excel file with an external add-in which has a custom formula for accessing data from the client server. The data changes every 5 min and I need to keep track of updated data every 5 min.

So, formula in an excel cell looks like:

```
=clientFormula("myvariable",,$B5,varID(C$4))
```

Where cells `B5` and `C4` have input parameters.

I am sure of neither of following approaches and google search doesn't reveal much either.

(1) Is there a way to read data output from the above formula in Python itself without opening the excel file?

If not,

(2) Is there a way to refresh the excel file using Python and read the data from excel. i.e. every time Python code runs it should be able to read the latest value from client server using the above formula and go on to do other things with that information.

Edit:
I did come across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989873/how-to-integrate-excel-rtd-function-in-python) but answer is from 2015.

Answer (score 0):

If I do not missundertstand that is similar of what I am doing.
I failed to use rtd client (trying to bypass excel real time data).
The cells in my case communicate with thinkorswim (rtd server with stock exchange data). I open the workbook using xlwings and read the cell changing value every few seconds. 
If I write the formula (string) from python to the cell I can do it but gives me a #¿NAME? error; if I press F2 and ENTER it writes the correct value but just that time. I had this problem when using:
    sheet.range((x, y)).value = list_of_formulas 
    sheet.range((x, y)).formula = list_of_formulas
and succeed with:
    sheet.range((x, y)).formula_array = list_of_formulas

You must use try/except since there are errors when reading.